# Need to suppress per patient

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Patient, Value, Problem, med 
FROM (((Have all this code right)
Group by  patient, value, problem, med
```

The report I have is all correct and prints perfect, I just need for it to suppress duplicates. I don't care if the patient has 4 values I only want to see one

```
NAme           Value         Problem    Med
Karen Life     20            ICD-427.31  Metro
Karen Life     19            ICD-427.31  Metro
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [help] docs on how to ask a question.  HOW are we possibly supposed to provide an answer when you show a section of your query, and none of the supporting table's schemas or sample data?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Which value do you want to see? Only one value per problem? Only one value per patient, per med?

Comment: If you mean duplicates by patient name, which `Value` do you want to pull?  Highest?  Sum? Average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is asking for a distinct list of the 4 fields...since value is '19' in one and '20' for the other, these rows are distinct and being returned by your query

Have any logic for which value you want?  If it doesn't matter, does it really need to be in your select statement?  If the value is numeric, this will work (I'm simply giving the max value)

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Patient, max(Value), Problem, med 
FROM (((Have all this code right)
Group by  patient, problem, med
```

edit:

This might be the simple solution...

```
SELECT Patient
FROM (((Have all this code right)
Group by  patient
```

That will give a list of all distinct patient names regardless of the number of value/med/problem combinations

Comment: Select Distinct has the 4 fields in which my from has the inner joins to match them to the patient. The value is an OBSVALUE in which the value can be any number. I tried doing the max but it didn't work, it still gives me 2 rows for same patient as the value is different.  I need the report to give me one patient even if the problem, meds, and value have multiple values so I am looking for a way to suppress and only show one row

Comment: When you do the max, remove the 'value' from the group by clause (if you leave it, you will get duplicates like you are seeing).  Hate to say it...but why not remove everything but the patient from your select and group by lines?  It'll just give you a distinct list of patients regardless of the prob/value/med.  put edit in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Patient, MAX(Value), Problem, med 
FROM (((Have all this code right)
GROUP BY  Patient,  Problem, med
```

Remove value from your GROUP BY and put a function on it depending on your needs. MAX, AVG, MIN, or a number of others depending on your needs